# cp returns before file is fully copied

Tags: raspberry-pi, julia

The julia `cp` seems to return before the file is actually fully copied on a Raspberry Pi (maybe 1 out of 3 times). Is this a bug? What can be done to ensure that the file is copied completely?

```
    wavname_example = "/some/file/foo.wav" #  68M in size
    wavname = "/tmp/foo.wav" 
    @show length(read(wavname_example))
    cp(wavname_example,wavname,force=true)
    @show length(read(wavname))
```

The output of this commands is:

```
length(read(wavname_example)) = 71159072
length(read(wavname)) = 8323072
```

I tried to add the sync command:

```
run(`sync`)`
```

But the problem persists. I use a ext4 file system on a SD card (Samsung EVO Plus microSDHC 32 GB).  26GB are still available on `/` (and `/tmp`). I am using julia 1.0.3 from Raspian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error does no longer show up once upgraded to julia 1.2.0.